# PHP MySQLI OOP not work

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I want to ask help for my MySQLI OOP. My MySQLI Class look like this:

```
Class DB {

    Private $connection;

    Public Function __construct($host = "localhost", $user = "root", $password = "", $db = "social_network") {

        $this->host = $host;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;

        $this->connection = @new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
        $this->connection->set_charset("UTF-8");

        if($this->connection->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Tietokantapalvelimeen ei saada yhteyttä [' . $this->connection->connect_error . ']');
        } else {

            if(!$this->connection->select_db($db)) {
                die('Tietokantaan ei saada yhteyttä: ' . $this->connection->error);
            }

            return $this->connection;
        } 

    }

    Public Function connect() {

        if(!$this->connection){
            return $this->connection;
        }

        return true;

    }

    Public Function disconnect() {

        if($this->connection){
            $this->connection->kill($this->connection->thread_id);
            $this->connection->close();
        }

        return true;

    }

    Public Function query($sql) {
        return $this->connection->query($sql);
    }

    Public Function result($sql) {
        $query = $this->connection->query($sql);

        if($query){
            $result = array();
            $i = 0;

            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                $result[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }

            return $result;

        } else {
            return print $this->connection->error;
        }

    }

    Public Function escape_string($sql) {
        return $this->connection->real_escape_string($sql);
    }

    Public Function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
    }

}
```

Example result:

```
$DB = new DB($_CONFIG['host'], $_CONFIG['user'], $_CONFIG['password'], $_CONFIG['db']);
$row = $DB->result("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = T0niiiiii LIMIT 1");
```

`print $row['username'];`

I get error **"Unknown column 'T0niiiiii' in 'where clause' "**.

So what is wrong? How i fix that? Or anyone know ready MySQLI OOP?

Comment: $row = $DB->result("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = 'T0niiiiii' LIMIT 1");

Comment: if you didn't catch that, 'T0niiiiii' needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Thanks! My bad, but now i try to <?PHP print $row['username']; ?> it's not display anything and not give error.

Comment: your fetching an onject, and returning an array. you would do something like `print $row[0]->username` do `var_dump($row)` to see  what you're working with.

Comment: @Pamblam i was trying to add that to my comment, and something weird happened and i ended up outside of the stacks. Thanks Pamblam!

Comment: @Pamblam, thanks for help! Its work now! I use `print $row[0]->username`

Comment: @AnonyymiPelaaja awesome! do me a favor and hit the checkmark by Phiter's answer below for answering your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wrap the value with apostrophes, MYSQL will 'think' you're referencing a column.

This should be your code:

```
$DB->result("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = 'T0niiiiii' LIMIT 1");
```

You didn't even need to ask in here, the error message says it all.

And about retrieving the row, you could do this:

```
$query = $DB->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = 'T0niiiiii' LIMIT 1");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->username;
   echo $row->password; //Never echo the password, this is just for testing :P
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I fix that. But when I use `<?PHP print $row['username']; ?>` it's not display anything or give error.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to pick the accepted answer if mine helped.